# How to configure dependencies in Python package with pyproject.toml or setup.cfg?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

## Overview

I am trying to package a simple script with 4 dependencies and am unable to define the dependencies such that they are installed correctly alongside the package when I try and install from test.pypi.org. I keep running into issues like: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <... e.g. pandas>` when I try installing the package.

## Build configuration files

I am using setuptools with a blank `setup.py` that looks like:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

A `pyproject.toml` that defines the build system as setuptools:

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
```

And a `setup.cfg` that declares some metadata, the console entry point, and the project dependencies:

```
[metadata]
name = nba_player_stats
version = 0.0.15

[options]
packages = src

install_requires =
    requests>"2.28"
    rich>"12.5"
    pandas>"1.5"
    lxml>"4.8"

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    nba = src.get_player_stats:main
```

## Dependency installation error

When I build the above package with `python -m build` and push to test.pypi with `twine` and then try installing in a fresh virtual environment with the following command: `python3 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ nba-player-stats --verbose`, I get the following error:

```
Using pip 22.3.1 from /home/ajpkim/baz/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting nba-player-stats
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/ee/5fb4d7643ee4085aa5e34c7e22076acf3ea6bc45bd09c5d4b8d308c77b2d/nba_player_stats-0.1.18-py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.28.1 (from nba-player-stats) (from versions: 2.5.4.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==2.28.1
```

## Similar dependency installation error after changing setup.cfg

I have tried several different ways of defining the deps including defining them in `setup` with `install_requires` as well as within `[project][dependencies]` in `pyproject.toml`, but haven't been able to successfully install the 4 deps with my package.

If I use the above files and comment out the `requests` line so `setup.cfg` looks like:

```
[metadata]
name = nba_player_stats
version = 0.0.16

[options]
packages = src
install_requires =
    # requests>"2.28"
    rich>"12.5"
    pandas>"1.5"
    lxml>"4.8"

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    nba = src.get_player_stats:main
```

Then, I get the following error when I try installing the package from test.pypi.org

```
Using pip 22.3.1 from /home/ajpkim/baz/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting nba-player-stats
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/79/4544424c06dc0d8235e479249b0d1020fc7d2ce956955abaee061e989808/nba_player_stats-0.0.15-py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
Collecting rich>"12.5"
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/e2/a002001a44f7f0a23324e30a8d2e3225b2703c3ec278f5c8bd29a078738d/rich-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>"1.5" (from nba-player-stats) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas>"1.5"
```

## Confused about packaging in general...

Things are changing (i.e. setup.py, setup.cfg, pyproject.toml) which makes it hard to learn best practices. If there is a better way to organize my build configuration please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[pip]+test.pypi.org

Comment: You limit your list of indices too much: instead of just `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/` use `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple`